# Fastest way to count folder files in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, file

I need to count the number of files in a folder in .NET 4:
The count will return number of all files except the .db file in the folder.

Option 1:

```
 IEnumerable<string> enumerables = Directory.EnumerateFiles(strPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
 int iNumFiles = 0; 
 foreach (string f in enumerables)
 {
    if (!f.EndsWith(".db"))
       iNumFiles++;
 }

 //iNumFiles is the count
```

Option 2:

```
int iNumFiles = 0; 
IEnumerable<string> enumerables1 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(strPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
IEnumerable<string> enumerables2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(strPath, "*.db", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

iNumFiles = enumerables1.Count() - enumerables2.Count();

//iNumFiles is the count
```

Is there any other simpler but better methods (using RegEx or something else) that I should use?

**EDIT:**
Should I keep the .db file or how useful it is? All I know it is the database (cache) of folder contents.

This is messing up my file count.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the *.* results into a queryable object.  then query out the *.db items.

`var queryObject = My.Computer.FileSystem.getFiles(foldername,       FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*").AsQueryable();`

`var filesIcareAbout = queryObject.where(f => right(f,3) != ".db");`

I took some syntax shorcuts.  This may not be exactly right syntactically.

Comment: Why would I use getFiles() instead of EnumerateFiles()?

Comment: You must instantiate a dirinfo object for enumerate.  Also, GetFiles() does have 2 overloads, which makes it a little more flexible??  Ultimately I'm just more familiar with GetFiles....I'd like to see a stack trace, I bet GetFiles calls EnumerateFiles

Answer (score -1):

```
new DirectoryInfo(strPath).EnumerateFiles("*.db").Count();
```

Comment: He needs the count of files that do not have a .db extension.

Comment: That returns the number of `*.db` files. OP wants the number of non-`*.db` files.